# How to configure terminal window to open on a specific default path?

Tags: command-line, paths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I start gnome-terminal at a particular directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75222/how-can-i-start-gnome-terminal-at-a-particular-directory)

At present, each time we open a terminal window we are placed inside our home directory.
`/home/myuser/`

I would like to change that path to be:
`/home/myuser/public_html/`

How can we do that?

Thanks.