# How do I change the default working directory with which gnome-terminal opens?

Tags: gnome-terminal

There does not seem to be any way to change this in the GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I start gnome-terminal at a particular directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75222/how-can-i-start-gnome-terminal-at-a-particular-directory)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Modify the `~/.bashrc` file and add this at the end:

```
cd /directory/of/your/choice
```

Save and close the file.

Now, every time you open a console session, you will be `cd`'d to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `~/.bashrc` was mapped to `/root/.bashrc`. I solved the problem by modifying `$HOME/.bashrc` instead, which maps to `/home/{username}/.bashrc`.