# Ubuntu 16.04: ' Open in Terminal' context menu on desktop opens it only in home directory

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 16.04, context-menu, nautilus-actions

1. Since upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, the desktop 'Open in Terminal' context menu opens only in home directory. It's realy uncomfortable.
   Is there a way to make it open with prompt in desktop directory ?
2. Is there a way to set a 'nautilus action' to display in the desktop context menu too .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the default working directory with which gnome-terminal opens?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180019/how-do-i-change-the-default-working-directory-with-which-gnome-terminal-opens)

Answer (score 3):

I have resolve the first point myself ;)

In fact, I want to open the terminal in the desktop only when I open it from desktop menu context or from the Unity Launcher.

So, all I have do is add this line at the end of my `.bashrc`:

```
[[ $PWD == $HOME ]] && cd $HOME/Desktop
```

---

<sub>With the question 1, I would like to know about a possible configuration point somewhere (i.e. `dconf`, `nautilus-actions`...).</sub>

<sub>Thank you for your answers.</sub>

Comment: Cool and easy solution, works on 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [How do I change the default working directory with which gnome-terminal opens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180019/how-do-i-change-the-default-working-directory-with-which-gnome-terminal-opens)

Modify the `.bashrc` file of the user you want the console to open in Desktop and add this at the end:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Save and close the file.

If you prefer to add settings but keep it separate from the original `.bashrc` you can edit the file and at the end put

```
if [ -f .bashrcc ];
then
    source .bashrcc
fi
```

Then create a file called `.bashrcc` and all entries will also be loaded when loading the shell.

This isn't useful to most but in my case I have a `.bashrc` that is just a link to a file that I have synchronized over several pc's  and this setup allows me to change the shell on one users without it changing it on all the pc's that the `.bashrc` is synchronized with. For instance if I wanted one user to have the availability of the alias `findzombie` I would add

```
alias findzombie='ps -A -ostat,ppid,pid,cmd | grep -e '^[Zz]' '
```

to the `.bashrcc` of that user and only he would have the use of that in his shell. Again probably not useful most and editing the `.bashrc` file is enough but though I would include it anyway

Comment: If it is a duplicate, you should flag it as such or leave a comment not copy someone elses answer and present it as your own -1

Comment: I'm new to this and don't know how to mark as duplicate and I basically added the link then relayed the pertinent information. I have seen others do this often. I also added to the information with information that may help others. Sorry if this offended you

Comment: "I have seen others do this often" They do it in comments though, thats the thing, we don't keep duplicate questions we remove them to keep the site clean and organized "Sorry if this offended you" Does not offend me, the downvote is just a good way to get peoples attention, here is some information on duplicates http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled I will remove my vote so you don't lose any rep.

Comment: I did follow though  and figured out how to mark as duplicate sorry for this again tho .. this wasn't meant to take someone's answer as my own. I was just trying to make an easy way for the guy to do what he asked. Sometimes people will report dups but they really aren't like especially when someone is having W10 / Ubuntu issues and people will mark it as a dup with instructions  to fix W7 issues .. and the changes in 10 make the instructions not completely relevant anymore. in this case Im sure that using the exact directory he wanted wasn't any more helpful than how the other person wrote it