# Open new Mate-Terminal in home folder

Tags: command-line, mate

I'm not sure if this is default behavior for `mate-terminal`. When I `cd` into a directory and then open a *new terminal tab*, it opens in the same folder.

I'd like this to default to home instead of the previous folder open.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT - I don't think this is a duplicate of [How can I start gnome-terminal at a particular directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75222/how-can-i-start-gnome-terminal-at-a-particular-directory) the difference is that I'm not starting a new terminal. If I open a fresh terminal it opens to $HOME which is what that question answers and how I expect it to behave. This question deals with new tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I start gnome-terminal at a particular directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75222/how-can-i-start-gnome-terminal-at-a-particular-directory)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, this is about to open a new tab with the default folder.

Comment: Updated the question with an edit as to why I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: Whats your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom command for your mate-terminal profile, eg:

```
sh -c "cd your_folder; exec bash"
```

Replace `your_folder` with your preferred folder and `bash` with your shell if you need another one than `bash`

[image]

---

The terminal in action

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

If you made a mistake use `dconf-editor` to correct your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Start `dconf-editor` and navigate to org.mate.terminal.profiles and change the values for `custom-command` and `use-custom-command`

[image]

Comment: @kos Yes, tested.

Comment: For that reason, my users are named `fab-user` and `fab-root`  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks, only small change was to use zsh instead of bash

Comment: @digital How funny, I also use zsh and have it specially modified.

Answer (score 1):

Googlers, if you rather want to open a new terminal tab (to have some convenience, while keeping the old tab open...)

```
mate-terminal --tab --working-directory=/home/frank/mount/bare
```

see `man mate-terminal`