# How to make crtl+alt+T to take you to a specific directory?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

It takes me by default to `/home/username`, but I have most of my things in the Desktop directory.. How to change it?
I was thinking of making a script like:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=~/Desktop
```

and then "associate" it with some keyboard short-cut if possible, but the above command doesn't work for me (it opens another terminal in /home/username). I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75222/how-can-i-start-gnome-terminal-at-a-particular-directory) question's first answer but I don't get how should I repair the bug (I wanted to ask for elaboration, but I haven't enough reputation...) . Also , I don't want to lose the "Open in terminal" option when right clicking, so adding `cd ~/Desktop` in `~/.bashrc` won't work for me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's possibly what you want. Works for me perfectly

First you need to install (other similar programs available too)  **xbindkeys**

`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`

Then create a default configuration file with

`xbindkeys --defaults`

(Prints the default configuration file)

So to create a configuration files with default values run

`xbindkeys --default > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`

Using ctrl+alt+T is not recommended in this case, since it is already in use. Find a unique key combination to use. I personally chose ctrl+shift + aring

You may want to use the following command to see exact names of the keys used

`xbindkeys -k`

After running the command, you need to hit the key combination. You will see an output similar to this

```
m:0x5 + c:34
  Control+Shift + aring
```

Then edit the configuration file you created with an editor of your choice

`vim .xbindkeysrc`

You will see that the only lines that are not commented out are

```
"xbindkeys_show"
  control+shift + q
```

That's one existing key combination

Add the following lines below the above mentioned lines

```
"gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/$USER/Desktop"
   control+shift + aring
```

(**If** you used different keys, add those **instead of** control+shift + aring)

The file around that area should be looking something like this

```
# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show"
   control+shift + q

"gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/$USER/Desktop"
   control+shift + aring

# set directly keycode (here control + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  c:41 + m:0x4
```

Save the file. After saving, you need to run the following command to activate key shortcuts for the session

```
xbindkeys
```

Now with the combination you set you should be able to open gnome-terminal to Desktop directory

**Note!** Using xbindkeys is explained very well and in more detail here

[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

See **Seth**'s excellent answer on that

Comment: Thanks for your time mate, but I think that just redirection to the other answer would have been enough :). Now, I've took the liberty to add a command I guess you missed.

Comment: I guess you are right about that :)